# Customize "Python Interactive" Window in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

Is there a way to customize (e.g., JSON config) the 'Python Interactive' Window to iPython/Jupyter console that comes with the MS Python extension?

I would like to be able to adjust the size of the variable explorer pane within the window (it can't currently be resized and takes up a bit of screen space.

I would also like the iPython console to look/operate like the native iPython console. That is, have an open console and be able to submit commands just by hitting enter (vs. the default `shift+enter`).  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have it look/operate like Spyder's interactive console.  Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

As a workaround I can launch an iPython session from the integrated terminal then select all code from the editor and send it to the terminal (which then gets sent into iPython), but this is not ideal and loses the advantage of the interactive window and the built-in variable explorer which is very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. We don't currently have these customizations that you are looking for. But if you would like to report these as enhancements then you could report them on our github here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues
That's the best way to get attention for adding a new feature.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will submit the enhancement requests through github.  Appreciate all the work you all have put into the extension thus far, it's great!

Comment: For anyone searching, I've opened a github ticket [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11869) that you may want to track if you're interested in these enhancements for yourself